# Custom layout instead of keyboard in Android

Tags: java, android, custom-keyboard

How can I create a custom layout instead of the keyboard in Android? something similar to the below image [paykey.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeXiW.png) knowing that the Keyboard class is deprecated. Note that I want it to be a service so that any application can use this keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Very basic example with custom `layout` for keyboard can be found at [here](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/creating-an-in-app-keyboard-for-your-android-apps-a0a6c6e1e289). You can extend this example with your need.

Comment: I want it to be a service so that any application can use this keyboard